# angularjs error on IE only with no debug option

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular application that run ok on chrome and firefox.

But on IE the application does not work.

My Big problem is that I can't find the error reason. and got some generic error.

How can I debug the application on IE or how can I find the reason for the Error

[image]

Comment: which version of IE? is it IE9? and does it work fine when IE console is open?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but u can replace `angular.min.js` if u have , with `angular.js`. it gives more detailed error . Just to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

**This means that ng module is failing to load. :)**
Please look at your browser's console to find if any files are missing or not being downloaded correctly. Also it helps if you click on the link to **http://errors.angularjs.org** in your console, it will give details about which particular module is failing to load.

**Check below link for complete details for resolution:**
http://blog.technovert.com/2014/10/dependency-injection-fails-angularjs/

**IE Debugging** : First of all you need to ensure your Angular application works on IE please consider the use *ng-style* tags instead of *style="{{ someCss }}"*. The latter works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in Internet Explorer <= 11. Arguably, this is the biggest annoyance of IE—the page just doesn’t load and doesn’t give any errors. Sometimes you need to view the page again in Firefox. If it’s not an IE specific error, Firebug will pick it up. If Firebug loads normally, the chances are it’s one of two IE specific errors: **a trailing comma, or unsupported XML syntax**.

Answer (score 0):

For minimize the application files I use

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/app").IncludeDirectory("~/Assets/app", "*.js", true)
               );
```

(Part of asp.net mvc)

And from the layout page I take all the application files

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/app")
```

Like I said this part of code worked for me in some browsers, But on IE It fail.

By Changing the script src to all specific files, I resolve this problem. and now on IE it work like the other browsers.

Maybe I miss a comma or ";" (end row) or something like that.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

need to check this page or api
http://henriquat.re/appendix/angularjs-and-ie8/necessary-changes-for-ie8-compatibility.html

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie